# Kafka multi site cluster - mirror maker tool

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to find multi-site model. Let's say there are many data centers at different located sites, i mean it may have latency between sites. In order to avoid latency, which architecture is the best for me?  I read about the mirror maker tool, as far as i understand it needs Kafka brokers on each site with producers and consumers, i will get data from producers from many sites but consume only at the central site, also i don't need many replicas and keeping data is not important as processing it at real time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mirror Maker enables you to replicate between multiple Kafka clusters, if that's what you require. You can't "avoid latency" as there's the speed of light to contend with ;-)

For a general overview of multi-DC deployments have a look at

- https://www.confluent.io/white-paper/disaster-recovery-for-multi-datacenter-apache-kafka-deployments/
- https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/

You'll need to give more specific details about your requirements if you want direct recommendations on an architecture. Can you explain why you're producing to multiple sites and consuming at one, if latency is a consideration? You could do a stretch cluster (one Kafka cluster across multiple sites) but you'll find ZooKeeper is sensitive to latency between sites, which can cause big problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know i meant side effects of latency :) Let me explain, our application will get real time traffic from different located sites and can process at one point because of data correlation, also at the center site our hw capacity is well enough for consumers. Actually at the beginning i thought one kafka cluster seems ok for this purpose but because of latency we may live problems, also you said samething that zookeeper is sensitive. Thats why i thought that we can use mirror maker tool. But i understand the purpose of using mirror maker is not for this.